# add a custom button Doclib-ribbon SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, spfx, spfx-extensions, modern

I would like to add a custom button on the default Document Library Ribbon.
You know, like next to 'new','share','automate','myCostumBtn'

Any of you guys a good suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SharePoint Online, I will suggest you to create a **ListView Command Set** for your document library using SPFx extensions.

Check below official documentations for same:

1. [Overview of SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions)
2. [Build your first ListView Command Set extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)

Comment: Hi @Emiel, Does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you and it will remove this question from unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0):

'CommandUI.Ribbon' user custom action is still supported in SP online. Please take a reference of below doc to get started:

- [CommandUI.Ribbon user custom actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries#commanduiribbon-user-custom-actions)

[image]

Of course SPFx extension is also a good option.

BR